# Can we run client programs written for HBase 0.94 using 0.94's client API on HBase 0.98 without having to modify or recompile them?

Tags: hbase, cloudera-cdh

HBase newbie here trying to get a client program written on HBase 0.94.19 version working with HBase 0.98.6 (CDH 5.2). I've added the HBase 0.98.6's jars to this client's classpath. I'm getting this error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Increment.setWriteToWAL(Z)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Increment`.

I saw the method signature in both the versions, and indeed there's a difference in the return type.

0.94's signature: http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Increment.html#setWriteToWAL(boolean) [`public Increment setWriteToWAL(boolean writeToWAL`] has a return type of Increment.

0.98's signature: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Mutation.html#setWriteToWAL(boolean) [`public void setWriteToWAL(boolean write)`
]

I read that Hadoop1 and Hadoop2 are binary compatible, but I'm not sure if that extends to HBase as well. So can I run this in any way so that I don't have to modify the code or recompile it? I guess not, but I'd like to hear from the experts here on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the api is not changed mutch, there may be deprecated methods but most of them should be the same.
but you must recompile against the new version. Even if we try to avoid the api changing too much, you must at least recompile between major releases.

Also between 94/96 there was a major rewrite in terms of rpc and wire-protocol, so that is another reason why you can't run directly a 94 client against a 96+ server.

Comment: Thanks, yes, looks like I can't escape recompiling.